# ElasticSearch Updates not recognized / Disable Docoument Versioning

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch 6.5.4 - currently I'm writing data once a day directly into several indexes simply via an POST Ajax Call where the ID will always be the same. Elastic then returns me that, if the ID didnt exist, the document was created - or if the ID exists, the document was updated.

Now I encountered a problem with versioning as it seems values dont update. Via the ElasticHead extension I'm looking in the details of the documents and I can see that I for example have the document stored as "version 9", but data fields like the index timestamp are still the ones from "version 1".

I've already checked, and I am not actually storing all versions - only the latest. Elastic just keeps an index of the versions. So I'm not quite sure, why for example the timestamp doesnt update.

What I want, is basically to disable versioning or somehow tell Elastic on every post call that the document I'm indexing is the current one and it should only use the current one for display. All similiar issues which I've found do not replicate my problem exactly, and none of the solutions could resolve it.

Does this issue occur because I'm using a simple POST Ajax Call? Could it be resolved by using Logstash as an ingest pipeline (which I'm planning to do anyways in further project progress)?

Example:

```
Data sent to Elastic
ajax.call - method.post - Result: 200
https://elasticURL.com/article/123456
{
     "customer": "Customer",
     "source": "Source",
     "categories": "/Category1/Category2/Category3/",
     "title": "My Title",
     "articletype": "MyType",
     "rating": 100,
     "ratingnormalized": 5,
     "views": 1234,
     "author": "Author",
     "timeindexed": "21/1/2019 10:00",
     "timeindexedDate": "21/1/2019",
     "timecreated": "13/10/2018 11:22",
     "timecreatedDate": "13/10/2018 ",
     "timeupdated": "13/10/2018 11:22",
     "timeupdatedDate": "13/10/2018 ",
     "url": "https://www.google.com",
     "category1": "Category: 1",
     "category2": "Category: 2",
     "category3": "Category: 3",
     "text": "MyText ",
     "html": "<html></html>"
}
```

```
Data stored in Elastic
{
"_index": "index_name",
"_type": "article",
"_id": "123456",
"_version": 3,
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
     "customer": "Customer",
     "source": "Source",
     "categories": "/Category1/Category2/Category3/",
     "title": "My Title",
     "articletype": "MyType",
     "rating": 100,
     "ratingnormalized": 5,
     "views": 1234,
     "author": "Author",
     "timeindexed": "04/1/2019 01:05",
     "timeindexedDate": "04/1/2019",
     "timecreated": "13/10/2018 11:22",
     "timecreatedDate": "13/10/2018 ",
     "timeupdated": "13/10/2018 11:22",
     "timeupdatedDate": "13/10/2018 ",
     "url": "https://www.google.com",
     "category1": "Category: 1",
     "category2": "Category: 2",
     "category3": "Category: 3",
     "text": "MyText ",
     "html": "<html></html>"
  }
}
```

Index Creation

```
PUT - https://elasticURL.com/index_name
{
    "settings" : {
        "index" : {
            "number_of_shards" : 5, 
            "number_of_replicas" : 0 
        }
    }
}
```

Index Mapping

```
PUT - https://elasticURL.com/index_name/_mappings
{
    "properties" : {
        "customer" : { "type" : "text" },
        "source" : { "type" : "text" },
        "categories" : { "type" : "text" },
        "articletype" : { "type" : "text" },    
        "title" : { "type" : "text" },
        "rating" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "ratingnormalized" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "views" : { "type" : "integer" },
        "author" : { "type" : "text" },
        "timeindexed" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"},
        "timeindexeddate" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"},
        "timecreated" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"},
        "timecreateddate" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"},
        "timeupdated" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"},
        "timeupdateddate" : { "type" : "date", "format" : "dd/MM/yyyy"},
        "url" : { "type" : "text" },
        "category1" : { "type" : "text" },
        "category2" : { "type" : "text" },
        "category3" : { "type" : "text" },
        "text" : { "type" : "text" },
        "html" : { "type" : "text" }
    }
}
+ keyword mapping for text fields, eg
        "text": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                }
            }
        },
```

To summarize this quickly;
For example the field timeindexed, doesnt update on a new POST to update the data. Only version increases. The elastic index shows docs: 4.498 (5.320).

Comment: May you please provide some data samples and queries to reproduce the problem? Elasticsearch only keeps the latest version of the indexed document, so you should see it updated. The details matter here, so it will help a huge bunch if you provide them. Thank you.

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev I've added examples to the main description, hope that helps

Comment: Sorry, I didn't manage to reproduce. I did one `POST /index_name/article/123456` with the document containing `"timeindexed": "04/1/2019 01:05",`, then again another `POST /index_name/article/123456` with the doc containing `"timeindexed": "21/1/2019 10:00",` and it resulted in the updated document with version bumped (both when fetching by ID and via `_search`). There is something more to your environment that affects the results.

Comment: How do you check that document was updated? Do you do a `GET /index_name/article/123456` or `POST /index_name/_search`? Do you have "vanilla" installation of ES or there are non-default settings?